# Shall I post an answer for the reputation earning?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

Today I just cam across one question that is [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265869/magento-2-2-6-installation-error-in-docker)

I simply understood the cause behind that error & placed one comment below the question & it solved the error that the P.O. of the question was facing.

Now my question is this shall I post one answer also there which is giving the same information or I should just leave it as it is. It is something like what one should do when he/she is knowing the answer & that answer he/she got to know from some resource

- He/she simply put one comment below the question with the link to that resource, from where the P.O. will definitely get the solution.
- For earning the reputation one should post it as an answer.

I know It is simply just a state of mind/choice of any person but then also I would like to have an opinion from the great contributors at M.S.E. to give their view on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Off course, you can give the answer to the question as the same type of issue you have faced and have resolved the issue by XYZ  procedure.

But the answer should not be One line or single link answer. You have to give some brief of how you have applied the solution on your case. That will help us with understanding.